# How to remove the space caused by Adsense ads while passing data from website to application?

Tags: android, webview

My code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.app.asiannews.model.Post;

public class ActivityWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private WebView webView;
    private Post post;
    private View parent_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        parent_view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        // get extra object
        post = (Post) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_OBJC);
        initToolbar();
        loadWebFromUrl();


        // analytics tracking
        ThisApplication.getInstance().trackScreenView("WebView : "+post.title_plain);
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Subhead);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.activity_title_webview);
    }

    private void loadWebFromUrl() {
        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(post.url);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                actionBar.setTitle( getString(R.string.webview_loading) + progress + " %");
                if (progress == 100) {
                    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.activity_title_webview);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh) {
            loadWebFromUrl();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I have added my code as shown above. There is space caused by the adsense ads which are implemetnted in the website. Now the problem is how to remove it.

My screen

[image]

Please give me the solution regarding it

Comment: go through this blog [post](http://www.hidroh.com/2016/05/19/hacking-up-ad-blocker-android/)

Comment: @Redman: does not work out

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the meta tag along with my HTML content before adding it to the Webview. Please find the Code below

```
 String s="<head><meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi'/></head>";            
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,s+htmlContent,"text/html" , "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: where.. please explain

Comment: can i use this as it is in my cide

Comment: here the htmlContent is referred then what its use

Comment: ur regular html content

Comment: I didnt understand that. please explain

Comment: i am talking about post.url

Comment: append the string s of the answer with post.url and apply it in the code